# Detectar duplicados en la misma fila ignorando NAs

Tags: r, string, eliminar-duplicados

Teniendo el data frame `input.df`:

| ID | LP1 | LP2 | LP3 | LP4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X1 | X2 | NA | NA |
| 2 | X1 | X2 | X3 | NA |
| 3 | X1 | X1 | NA | NA |
| 4 | X1 | X2 | X2 | NA |
| 5 | X1 | NA | NA | NA |

Me gustaría detectar los valores duplicados en una misma fila ignorando los NAs, es decir solo los casos con ID=3 e ID=4 donde los X1 y X2 están duplicados. He utilizado el siguiente código pero extrae todos los valores porque cuenta los NAs como si fueran duplicados.

```
xx <- input.df[duplicated(input.df[,c("LP1","LP2","LP3","LP4"]),]
```

Lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente:

| ID | LP1 | LP2 | LP3 | LP4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | X1 | X1 | NA | NA |
| 4 | X1 | X2 | X2 | NA |

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría en un doble proceso.

Primero, transformo los datos a formato largo y ahí por ID busco los que son duplicados. Y Segundo, lo que hago es unirlo con el data frame original, para obtener en el formato que indicas.

```
dd %>% inner_join(dd %>% gather(key, value, 2:5) %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(duplicated(value)) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% select(ID))
```

```
  ID LP1 LP2  LP3 LP4
   3  x1  x1 <NA>  NA
   4  x1  x2   x2  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo con R base seria la siguiente:

```
input.df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  LP1 = c("X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1"),
  LP2 = c("X2", "X2", "X1", "X2", NA),
  LP3 = c(NA, "X3", NA, "X2", NA),
  LP4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)


filtro<-apply(input.df,1,function(x){
    any(duplicated(x[!is.na(x)]))
})

input.df[filtro,]
```

La función `apply` se utiliza para aplicar una función a lo largo de las filas del dataframe. En este caso, se aplica una función anónima que toma una fila del dataframe como argumento `x`.

La función `duplicated` devuelve un vector lógico que indica si un elemento de `x` es igual a uno anterior en la misma fila.

La función `any` devuelve `TRUE` si al menos uno de los valores del vector es `TRUE`. Por lo tanto, la función anónima devuelve `TRUE` si hay al menos una celda en la fila que contiene un valor duplicado y no es un valor `NA`.

Con el filtro `x[!is.na(x)]` eliminamos los `NA` antes de usar `duplicated`.

La variable `filtro` es un vector lógico que indica qué filas del `dataframe` tienen valores duplicados en las columnas, excepto en las celdas con valores `NA`.

Finalmente, se utiliza la variable `filtro` para subconjuntar el `dataframe` `input.df`, de tal manera que se eliminan las filas que cumplen la condición que mencionas.